# Not able to find ODBC Driver for Oracle Database 11g

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, odbc

thought i have Oracle Database 11g Installed i am not getting ODBC driver. can any one tell me what is the problem with it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to put an appropriate jdbc driver explicitly in your classpath. Drivers are here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-111060-084321.html

Comment: i need ODBC driver for oracle 11g db